# JSF 1.2 with Trinidad - using fileDownloadActionListener

Tags: download, jsf-1.2, trinidad

I'm using the DownloadFile Listener in my application as follow :

```
<tr:commandButton value="Say Hello">
     <tr:fileDownloadActionListener filename="hello.txt"
         contentType="text/plain; charset=utf-8" method="#{bean.sayHello}"/>
</tr:commandButton>
```

"method" is The method that will be used to download the file contents. 
The method takes two arguments, a FacesContext and an OutputStream.

I'm using this listener in two different place in the app.
while in the first place the outputStream is in XMLOutput Format - the downloading does not working
the second place I'm using this listener the outputSteam is of other format and the downloding process works.

My Question is how JSF/Trinidad Decided about the outputStream Format and if that is actually the problem that that downloing is not working.

Comment: Btw , in the second place I'm using the downloadlistebner outputStream is of type CoyoteOutputStream and the downloaind is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the in the second place I used the filedownload listener I tried to work with PPR -
Trinidad Ajax built in. and apparently this mix does not work. so I removed the ppr.

If anyone knows how to mix them OR can explain why they don't work together I'll be glad to understand.

Thanks.